# Supercapacitor spot welder - which capacitors to use?

Tags: voltage, power, capacitor, discharge, supercapacitor

I built a spot welder using a big transformer (approximately 4kW from an old welding machine) but I now need to build a spot welder with more power (more current.)

The current spot welder works great for steel/nickel coated steel but lacks power for spot welding copper.

The 4kw transformer welder has approximately 8V open circuit voltage. I am using 35mm2 copper wire, approximately 1 meter total wire length (back and forth) from the transformer to the spot welding electrodes.

I think using super capacitors is my best option for building a higher power spot welder.

According to my research I need approx 3000 amperes-4000 amperes of current to weld 0.2mm copper (which is my goal.) The capacitor discharge time should be <20ms if possible (the lower the better I think.) PS: this amperage amount is based off of the following website: https://sunstonewelders.com/product/linear-dc/ and a comment under the following video where Sunstone comments that for welding two plates of 0.25mm copper together with this machine you need approx 4000 amperes (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16JOF-bYgWE)

Would something like this (or a combination of a few/many of these in series/parallel) be suitable for this purpose?

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32950120538.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1fc72679PGnQqn&algo_pvid=e5b35dfe-59f6-40ee-92cd-bb0dd81b5685&algo_expid=e5b35dfe-59f6-40ee-92cd-bb0dd81b5685-11&btsid=7ac9af34-07ad-405d-a2b8-8a1f6cfae7c3&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_8,searchweb201603_52

What open circuit voltage should I be aiming for approximately to achieve the desired amperage? What would be a suitable capacitance value for the capacitor bank?

The spot welder pen I'll be using: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000159606521.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.46332b7duxXLLm&algo_pvid=86b2cbd1-50eb-4bf4-b0f7-9a33915fa1dc&algo_expid=86b2cbd1-50eb-4bf4-b0f7-9a33915fa1dc-2&btsid=0e8acf7d-32fb-440e-badc-79556c2d2698&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_8,searchweb201603_52

[image]

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most super capacitors have too high ESR for your purpose, but not all. Have you done any calculations of how much ESR you can tolerate? Rough rule of thumb: ns = ceramics, us = plastic, ms = electolytics, s = supercapacitors and hours = batteries.

Comment: @winny i will try to make a calculation tomorrow and will post the results in my original post.